# How to handle multiple websites using one PAYPAL Business account?

Tags: php, paypal

i want to use one account with multiple websites so it transfers all paypal balance in one accounts.

now if i redirect it with dynamically using CURL then it gives blank payment response and it gives a popup with continue button and firefox first redirect to that page and mobile browsers also get blank response because of SSL.

And when i follow the steps of Paypal PDT steps it redirects from both websites to a same defined URL as per steps. steps are given in this page. ([CLICK FOR PDT STEPS](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/paymentdatatransfer/))

And i don't want to create two business accounts in one payple account so can i handle multiple website payments in one business account...?
if yes then how it will possible?

in sort i want to handle multiple websites using single BUSINESS account without getting ssl warning in any website while it redirects from PAYPAL after paypal transaction.

Answer (score 1):

How about notify_url variable? 
It's called differently in regards to API you are using. More details: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNSetup/

Comment: Using PDT steps you can specify both return url (customers will be redirected there after successful/cancelled payment) and notification url (Paypal will notify this URL about completed transactions)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the page_style variable.

PayPal allows you to create several page styles in your account (no additional accounts required). You can read [here for instructions on how to customize these page styles](https://www.paypal.com/customize).

Once you have your page styles ready you can use them in the form or button with the page_style variable by giving it as value the name of a specific page style you created on your account :

```
<input type="hidden" name="page_style" value="somestyle">
```